# Error with adding element to list - repeating n-time last element

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist, addition

Could anyone help me and point out what is wrong here? All the fields are non-static. Function shuffle returns each time different array.

```
List<Point[]> someArray = new ArrayList<Point[]>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Point[] temporary = new Point[50];
    temporary = shuffle(pointsArray.getPoints());
    someArray.add(temporary);
    print(someArray.get(i));
}
```

The result of print in the first loop is ok since they're different. Right after getting out of the loop, I want to print elements of list someArray again.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    print(someArray.get(i));
}
```

The result here is 4 time of the last element.

Comment: It looks like `pointsArray.getPoints()` is returning original points collection/array instead of its copy, so each time you are calling `shuffle` you are shuffling and returning same collection/array of points. OR `getPoints()` returns copy of array holding points, but it doesn't create deep copy (where it returns also copy of points) but different array still filled with same points as are held by original array.  It is hard to tell without seeing [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))
.

Comment: @user2633746 thank you for the answer, I solved this problem yesterday by declaring a new array and copied entirely pointsArray.getPoints() there. As I said each time shuffle returned a different array because the result of print(someArray.get(i))is different, I just don't understand why each time when someArray added the new object, all its objects change to the new one. Printing result example: Right after adding: 1 2 3, 1 3 2, 3 2 1 After completely built: 3 2 1, 3 2 1, 3 2 1 I'm a beginner so I would very appreciated if someone could explain the problem to me.